# How to POST following data using retrofit

Tags: android, post, retrofit2

I want to post the following JSON object in a POST request over retrofit

```
{
"Inputs": {
"input1": {
  "ColumnNames": [
    "Name",
    "Weekday",
    "Time",
    "Type"
  ],
  "Values": [
    [
      " ",
      "1",
      "9:00:34",
      "OUTGOING"
    ],

  ]
}}
```

How do I represent this as a GSON object? I have only found very easy examples online (like {'Foo':'bar'} sort). Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to generate the java classes

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "Inputs": {
        "input1": {
            "ColumnNames": [
                "Name",
                "Weekday",
                "Time",
                "Type"
            ],
            "Values": [
                [
                    " ",
                    "1",
                    "9:00:34",
                    "OUTGOING"
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like you have an "input" object, containing a string array (ColumnNames) and a two dimensional string array (Values).  You could interpret it as a java model object like the following

```
class Input {
    String[] ColumnNames;
    Value[][] Values;
}
```

You can then use a json library like Gson to convert your json to and from this model object, eg `new Gson().fromJson(jsonInput, Input.class)`.

The json you actually have shown us wraps your Input object in two other objects though, so make sure to handle them appropriately.